# Cloudfront Origin Request Lambda to modify request uri AND response cache headers

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront origin-request Lambda which takes a uri and query string parameters and determines which file in S3 is best suited to serve the request.

The query parameters are `width` and `height` and appropriately configured in the Cache policy and origin request policies so that they're part of the cache key and available in the origin request.

For example, if the request URI is `/video.mp4?width=500`, the Lambda looks in S3 for an exact or closest match and updates the request.uri property; if there are no suitable files, it just returns `video.mp4`. Cloudfront then caches this request so subsequent requests to /video.mp4?width=500 don't hit S3.

In an error state it is important that the request does not fail, so the original request is passed through and `video.mp4` is returned. The problem is that said error state is then cached for the same length of time as the correct response. I need the lambda to run more frequently in an error state so I can report on errors effectively.

Typically in these scenarios I simply set the cache headers in the response and return a response instead of a request from the lambda. I have been unable to determine what my response structure should look like to send the correct video back. Obviously setting the `body` property is not appropriate as it's a video and would be larger than the 4MB limit.

What might a response object look like for a file > 4MB so I can spoof an s3 response and modify cache headers from within the Lambda?

I have also returned redirect responses to the correct file in other implementations, but in this situation, I must return the video from the original request.

Are there any suggestions on a different approach?